# Convert text data file to csv format

Tags: vb.net

My text data file is like this:

```
{1000}xxx{1200}xxx{3000}xxxxxx{5000}
{1000}xx{1500}xxxxxx{4000}xx{6000}
{1000}xxxx{1600}xxx{3000}xxx{6000}
...
```

I need to convert this data file to csv file or excel file to analyze. I tried Excel or other convert software. But it is  not working.

Can I use VB to do that? I did not use VB for a long time (over 10 years).

I am sorry. I did not make it clear.

The number in curly brackets is the field name. Each record doesn't have same field. The result after converted should be like this:

```
(header line) 1000  1200 1500 1600 3000 4000 5000 6000
(record line)  xxx   xxx            xxx       xxx
      .        xxx        xxx            xxx       xxx
      .        xxx             xxx  xxx            xxx
```

We have the text data file everyday (10 - 20 records).  Although data is not big, we don't need to re-type to excel file if we can convert to csv file. This can help us lot of time.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 0):

You almost definitely could use a programming language (like VB) to make this change.  I'm not sure you need to do that though.

If you are trying to write a program to convert the same type of file over and over, it might make sense to build a program in VB.net.

FYI, its hard to help advise you further without understanding more about what you need to do?  For example, the size of the file, how often you will need to do it, what the target format will be, etc...

...  but the answer I provided did answer the question you asked!  ... and I am seeking rep points ;)

Comment: Reputation points here are generally awarded for solving a problem. If a problem was not clearly described, try finding it out via comments to the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. We do this convert everyday. Although The data volumn is not big. Everyday has 10-20 transaction. the number in the curly bracket actually is the field name. Every record doesn't have the same fields. We tried to convert this text data file to csv or excel file.

Comment: Neolisk, one thing i'm trying to get is the ability to post comments :(.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your explanation of how the data is structured:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Class Cell
        Property ColumnName As String
        Property Value As String

        ' To help with debugging/general usage
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("Col: {0} Val: {1}", ColumnName, Value)
        End Function
    End Class

    Dim table As New List(Of List(Of Cell))

    Sub Main()
        Dim src As String = "C:\temp\sampledata.txt"
        Dim dest = "C:\temp\sampledata.csv"

        Dim colNames As New List(Of String)

        ' This regex will look for zero or more characters ".*" surrounded by braces "\{ \}" and
        ' collect the zero or more characters in a group "( )". The "?" makes it non-greedy.
        ' The second capture group "( )" gets all the characters up to but not including
        ' the next "\{" (if it is present).
        Dim cellSelector = New Regex("\{(.*?)\}([^\{]*)")

        ' Read in the cells and record the column names.
        Using inFile = New StreamReader(src)
            While Not inFile.EndOfStream
                Dim line = inFile.ReadLine
                Dim rowContent As New List(Of Cell)
                For Each m As Match In cellSelector.Matches(line)
                    rowContent.Add(New Cell With {.ColumnName = m.Groups(1).Value, .Value = m.Groups(2).Value})
                    If Not colNames.Contains(m.Groups(1).Value) Then
                        colNames.Add(m.Groups(1).Value)
                    End If
                Next
                table.Add(rowContent.OrderBy(Function(c) c.ColumnName).ToList)
            End While
        End Using

        colNames.Sort()

        ' add the header row of the column names
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(String.Join(",", colNames) & vbCrLf)

        ' output the data in csv format
        For Each r In table

            Dim col = 0
            Dim cellNo = 0

            While cellNo < r.Count AndAlso col < colNames.Count
                ' If this row has a cell with the appropriate column name then
                ' add the value to the output.
                If r(cellNo).ColumnName = colNames(col) Then
                    sb.Append(r(cellNo).Value)
                    cellNo += 1
                End If

                ' add a separator if is not the last item in the row
                If col < colNames.Count - 1 Then
                    sb.Append(","c)
                End If

                col += 1

            End While

            sb.AppendLine()

        Next

        File.WriteAllText(dest, sb.ToString)

    End Sub

End Module
```

From your sample data, the output is

```
1000,1200,1500,1600,3000,4000,5000,6000
xxx,xxx,,,xxxxxx,,,
xx,,xxxxxx,,,xx,,,
xxxx,,,xxx,xxx,,,,
```

I notice that none of the final columns have data in them. Is that just a copy-and-paste error or intentional?

EDIT: I use **Option Infer On**, which is why some of the type declarations are missing.